# Combine two lists with linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists:

```
    var myIds = new List<int>()
        {
            1, 2, 3
        };

    var yourIds = new List<int>()
        {
            2, 3, 4
        };
```

How could I combine the two lists into one. The new list would look like this:

```
Id    Mine     Yours
---------------------
1      T         F
2      T         T
3      T         T
4      F         T
```

Both contain integers and vary only in name. I thought about creating two additional lists with a property that represented the name of each list, but I'm sure there is a better way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
myIds.Union(yourIds)
.Select(x => new 
             { 
                 Id = x,
                 Mine = myIds.Contains(x), 
                 Yours = yourIds.Contains(x)
             });
```

Comment: it would be better with some explanation / comment

Comment: The Union basically do the job of merge the lists, what he is doing after that is just creating an anonymous object with the properties that are in the example, the "Contains" will return a boolean value, this way he reply the original ask.